# How to access the Parent Object when i identified its Child Object in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I dont know how to access the Parent Object when i know its Child Object

Ive setup joints on a rope that contain colliders but not on the actual parent gameobject.

i put a tag on the first joint (child Object) and would like to destroy the entire rope on collision.

```
  void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Destroy Rope");
        Debug.Log("Joint Name" + col.gameObject.name);
    }
}
```

Anyone help this noobie question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `childObject.transform.parent.gameObject` for this

Comment: if i try Destroy (col.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);  this just crashes the editor.....

Comment: Where in your code is that method `void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)`

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log("Destroy Konyaku");
            Debug.Log("Joint Name" + col.gameObject.name);
            
            Destroy (col.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
        }
    }

Comment: Im asking are you sure that this `col` belong to this child object. You can check it by just `Debug.Log(col);`

Comment: im positive since, ive only set the first joint tagged Player, everything else is untagged on the rope

Comment: this is the child of the rope prefab as well

Comment: can you place screenshoot of your Hierarchy and mark to which gameObject this method is attached?

Comment: how do you add images on this thing?

Comment: Ok, before this screenshot try this. Maybe you have any dependencies to this rope? Try to type not destroy but just: `Debug.Log(col.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);` And look on Console

Comment: Ok It looks good, now run just `Debug.Log(col.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);` instead of destroy and show results

Comment: it logs the actual name of the parent gameobject   http://www.thecasualmeta.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/heir2.png

Comment: why does destroy(col.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);  crash the editor?

Comment: OK, in my opinion, you can mark this question as answered and ask new question and provide more detail about this error, because question about (access the Parent Object) 
is already answered

Comment: And this `destroy(childObject.gameObject.transform.parent.gameObject);` works in my project so it's hard to say without more details. So better ask new question directly about that :)

Comment: which version of Unity do you use? and can you provide some Info from the Crash Log from unity? this may help to find the problem